# Ionic fixed bottom div and slide up animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, ionic-framework

I would like to achieve following effect in ionic framework. When i click on the arrow, the boxes will slide up as in the right. When i click the arrow or any other area except the text box, it will return to original position. It should be appearing under any view that have menu.html as abstract view. How could it be done? I try my first step as below but nothing is appear.

Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BNK5R0?p=preview)

```
<ion-side-menus>

  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-chevron-left"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-pane>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </header>
    <ion-content class="has-header">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/search">
          Search
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/browse">
          Browse
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
          Playlists
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>

<!-- Nothing appear -->
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 200px;">Text here</div>
```

[image]